# ASP TableAdapters. Getting row data from a SQL parameter query

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Trying to get my head round ASP.NET DALs and TableAdapters and I'm hoping somebody can help me with getting the column data when using SQL query parameters.

If I have a TableAdapter with a query that returns one or more rows, I can get row and column data from the datatable no problem. For a simple query which returns one row I can use:

```
SQL: SELECT firstName, lastName from Names WHERE ID=1

Dim MyAdapter1 As New ProjectTableAdapters.NamesTableAdapter1
Dim f As String = MyAdapter1.GetNames.Rows(0)("firstName")
Dim l As String = MyAdapter1.GetNames.Rows(0)("lastName")
```

However if use a TableAdapter which has a query with a parameter I keep getting exceptions thrown. I'm sure this is simple, if someone can point me in right direction (vb if possible). Thanks a lot.

```
SQL: SELECT firstName, lastName from Names WHERE ID=@ID

Dim ID As Integer = 1
Dim MyAdapter2 As New ProjectTableAdapters.NamesTableAdapter2
Dim f As String = MyAdapter2.GetNames(Rows(0)("firstName"),ID)   [throws exection]
```

Edit:
I think I have it working now - my bad syntax...

```
Dim f As String = MyAdapter2.GetNames(ID).Rows(0)("firstName")
```

Comment: That first code snippet is very, very bad. That `GetNames` method actually queries the database and returns a populated `DataTable`. You're calling that method twice, so you're querying the database twice and getting the data twice. You should be calling it once only and assigning the result to a variable, then getting the first row from that DataTable and assigning it to a variable, then getting the two field values from that row.

Comment: Very good point, thank you. I will change it as you suggest - and for the query with parameters.
I can see the benefit of assigning a variable to the DataTable, but is there much of an advantage in also assigning a variable to the row - other than making the code easier to read.

Comment: Any object that needs to be used more than once should be assigned to a variable, either explicitly or implicitly using a `With` block. In actual fact, based on just the code you posted, there actually isn't a need to assign the `DataTable` to a variable because the `DataTable` only needs to be used once, i.e. to get the `DataRow`. It's the `DataRow` that actually must be used twice, i.e. to get two field values, so it should be assigned to a row, e.g. `Dim row = MyAdapter1.GetNames().Rows(0)`. You can then use `row("firstName")` and `row("lastName")`.

Comment: By the way, as you're using a typed `DataSet`, you don't need to use the `Rows` property. Doing so gets you an untyped `DataRow` reference. If you index the typed `DataTable` itself then you'll get a typed `DataRow` reference: `Dim row = MyAdapter1.GetNames()(0)`. `row` will then be type `NamesDataRow` or something like that. It will then have a property for each field so you don't have to index using magic strings, e.g. `Dim f = row.firstName`.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks for your help. My code is looking much cleaner now.

Comment: I did end up declaring the DataTable variable first, then the Row variable, as it means I can check the .Count to make sure I have a row returned. Didn't know that you don't need the .Rows property - and not a great fan of the magic string syntax. Having a property for each field is much cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function MyFunction() As DataSet
        Dim conString As String = "Connection String"
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(conString)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand With {
            .Connection = conn,
            .CommandText = "SELECT firstName, lastName from Names WHERE ID=@ID",
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text}
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        conn.Open()
        da.Fill(ds)
        conn.Close()
        Return ds
    End Function
```

Comment: Sure that would work fine. I have written apps with this type of code, but I'm having a go at using the DAL / BLL model for this app.